# Questions pertaining to micro-service architecture

Tags: node.js, go, microservices

I have a couple of questions that exist around micro service architecture, for example take the following services:

*orders*,
*account*,
*communication* & 
*management*

Question 1: From what I read I understand that each service is suppose to have ownership of the data pertaining to that service, so orders would have an orders database. How important is that data ownership? Would micro-services make sense if they all called from one traditional database such that all data pertaining to the services would exist in one database? If so, are there an implications of structuring the services this way.

Question 2: Services should be able to communicate with one and other. How would that statement be any different than simply curling an existing API? & basing the logic on that response? Is calling a service more efficient than simply curling the API?

Question 3: Is it worth it? Now I understand this is a massive generality , and it's fundamentally predicated on the needs of the business. But when that discussion has been had, was the re-build worth it? & what challenges can you expect to face

Comment: rule of thumb, If you are starting project from initial stage and you do not have  domain(technical/product) knowledge go for monolith, because when requirements will change you will eventually break the isolation. If you have strong expertise in either then or you have a bigger project which is getting difficult to scale choose micro. :)

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer all the questions.

1. Respect to all services using the same database. If you do so you have two main problems. First the database would become a bottleneck because all requests will go to the same point. And second you will have coupled all your services, so if the database goes down or it needs to update, all your services will be affected. (The database will became a single point of failure)
2. The communication between services could be whatever your services need (syncrhonous, asynchronous, via message passing (message broker), etc..) it all depends on the use cases you have to support. The recommended way to do to avoid temporal decoupling is to use a message broker like kafka, doing this your services don't have to known each other and in case some of them go down the others will still working. And when they are up again, they can continue to process the messages that have pending. However, if your services need to respond in synchronous way, you can define synchronous communication between services and use a circuit breaker to behave properly in case the callee service is down.
3. Microservices architecture is far more complicated to make it work, to monitoring and to debug than a traditional monolith architecture so, it is only worth if you will have very large requirements of scalability and availability and/or if the system is very large and it will require several teams working in different parts of the system and it is recommendable to avoid dependencies among them. So each team can work at their own pace deploying their own services

Comment: Hey thanks for responding. 

In response to the first question how's that any different from having multiple apis reading from the same database?  if the database goes down all API's will be affected? I imagine bottle necking occurs in monolithic structures too

Comment: if you have only one database, it will became automatically a SPF because if it fails, all services will fail, even if you are using different APIs because all of them will make request to the same database. Instead of this, if every service use its own datastore and some of them fail, it will only affect the services connected to those datastores allowing the whole application continue to work using some kind of fallback